# can't connect java application to wampserver database on another computer

Tags: java, mysql, wampserver

I am able to connect successfully to my database through localhost with my application. but I am trying to have that same application on another computer and share the same database with the first computer.

I am using wampserver 3.2.0 (64bit) and windows 10 pro.

This is what I tried:

1. I went to httpd-vhosts.conf of my wampserver and changed 'Require local' to 'Require all granted'
2. Then I went to my user account of wampserver and added an new user privilege, and replaced the hostname with '%' instead of 'localhost' with a new username and password.
3. Typed ipconfig in CMD and copied my ipv4 address, into my connection URLin replacement of localhost. eg: `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1/mydatabase","user","pass");`

This connection is for the app on the different computer, whilst maintaining localhost connection URL for the main computer which has the wampserver. Both computers are connected to the same wireless router.

Anytime I run the application on the other computer, I get this exception:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exexceptions.CommunicationsXeception:Communications
> link Failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0
> milliseconds ago. The driver has not recieved any packets from the
> server

Comment: Did you check the Firewall

Comment: Probably the bind-address in your MySQL configuration is set to 127.0.0.1, accepting only connections to localhost, or Windows firewall doesn't allow connections from other machines to MySQL.

Comment: please how do i find the bind-address in wamp64 folder. and if permissions must be granted in firewall, how do i allow connection through firewall @MarkRotteveel

Comment: `192.168.0.1` is Most likely your Routers ip address!

Comment: Find out what firewall you are using and look up how to allow a connection through it on port 3306